# jQuery tag-it - wrong use of replace()?

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I have a question for those of you who worked with the tag-it jQuery plugin (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it). 
I looked over the code and I noticed something which is unclear for myself.
I'm talking about the replace() from
`$.trim(that.tagInput.val()).replace( /^s*/, '' ).charAt(0) != '"'`  condition at line 254. 
First I thought that it should be `replace( /^\s*/, '' )`, then I noticed the call of $.trim().

Does someone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

`trim` removes all whitespace at start and end.

`/^s*/` means "match all 's' chars at start of the expression".

Comment: My bad. I'm not asking what trim or the regular expression are doing, but what's the logic of having that replace() in that if statement?